# Get the row count of an XLSX file

Tags: macos, xls, xlsx

I want to create a list of all the `.xlsx` files on my computer and the number of rows in them.

What is the best way to get the # of rows in each `.xlsx` file?  I'm on Mac OSX Yosemite (if it's relevant).  The answer can be in any language.

Comment: Sprechen Sie Deutsch ? ;-) You could use Java and Apache POI to read and count the number of rows.

Comment: Upvote for the joke that took me a minute... and for Apache POI. Looks like it only supports 2007, know of anything that also does XLSX?

Comment: Could not resist ;-) I use POI to read xlsx created by Word 2010, this works for sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with PHP and Spout (https://github.com/box/spout).
The code would look something like this:

```
use Box\Spout\Reader\ReaderFactory;
use Box\Spout\Common\Type;

// This is the root directory you want to list the XLSX files of
// CHANGE IT !!
$rootPath = '/path/to/root/directory';

// this will read the XLSX file at the given path and return the number of rows for the file
function getNumRows($xlsxPath) {
    $numRows = 0;

    $reader = ReaderFactory::create(Type::XLSX);
    $reader->open($xlsxPath);

    foreach ($reader->getSheetIterator() as $sheet) {
        foreach ($sheet->getRowIterator() as $row) {
            $numRows++;
        }
    }

    $reader->close();

    return $numRows;
}

// This will recursively go through the root folder and all its subfolders
$directoryIterator = new \RecursiveDirectoryIterator($rootPath, RecursiveDirectoryIterator::SKIP_DOTS);
$recursiveIterator = new \RecursiveIteratorIterator($directoryIterator, RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);

foreach ($recursiveIterator as $fileInfo) {
    if (strtolower($fileInfo->getExtension()) === 'xlsx') {
        $xlsxPath = $fileInfo->getPathname();
        $numRows = getNumRows($xlsxPath);
        // store the number of rows for the file somewhere
    }
}
```